# Intersect between Surface and Ray

Tags: arcobjects, intersection

I am interested in finding the intersection of a Ray and a Surface in ArcObjects.

I already know of two solutions.  First solution is to use the `Locate` method of [ISurface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISurface_Interface/002500000877000000/):

```
Dim intersectionPoint As IPoint = surface.Locate(ray, hint)
```

The other solution is to use the `GetLineOfSight` method of [IGeoDatabaseBridge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000395000000) (where the variable `point` is a calculated point along the path of the ray):

```
Dim geoDatabaseBridge2 As IGeoDatabaseBridge2 = New GeoDatabaseHelper
geoDatabaseBridge2.GetLineOfSight(surface, baseRay.Origin, point, intersectionPoint, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, False, False)
```

Surprisingly, the `GetLineOfSight` method is much faster than the `locate` method.  But I am looking for an even faster solution.

So my question is:  Is there any other (and faster) ways to find the intersection between a ray and a surface?  Or can you point me in the direction of literature that explains the calculations I need to roll my own?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I have started the process of creating my own Line of Sight algorithm.  I have posted my current solution description in a [blog post](http://blog.gisinc.com/2011/12/15/towards-a-high-performance-line-of-sight-tool/).  Thanks again for all of the suggestions.

Comment: Is your surface based on a TIN or raster?

Comment: The surface is based on a raster

Comment: Are you wanting to stick with ArcObjects? If not, have you searched for [using GPU for line of sight](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=gpu+line+of+sight)?

Comment: I would prefer to stick with ArcObjects.  But if ArcObjects can't do it, I'll look for other options.

Comment: If your users are accustomed to video game performance levels, I don't think you'll satisfy them unless you leverage a GPU.  How much faster does it need to be?

Comment: I am running an algorithm that requires the calculation of 50,000+ line of sight calculations.  I will look into GPU calculations, as that would drastically increase performance.  I also need a non GPU solution because I am not willing to mandate GPUs to run the algorithm.  For a non GPU solution I would be happy with 1-10 times faster.

Comment: @Chris Small things make big differences.  Different approaches may be best if (a) all lines of sight emanate from the same point and use the same DEM; (b) different DEMs are used; (c) a single DEM is used and all lines of sight lie above a common point; (d) there are known bounds on the slopes of the DEM; etc.  It would therefore help for you to disclose more about what you really want to accomplish and some details about the nature of the surface and these rays.

Comment: @whuber: Understood.  I am using a single DEM.  The points are all over the map.  There are no guaranteed bounds on the slope of the DEM.

Comment: @Kirk, my eventual problem will be probably solved by moving away from ArcObjects and pursuing a GPU solution.

Comment: @whuber, In the more immediate solution, I will take you comment: "Small things make a big differ.  Different approaches may be best"  The `GetLineOfSight` calculation is the bottleneck of the algorithm, and I am in the process of reworking the algorithm to call the `GetLineOfSight` method less often.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @chris if disk i/o is the bottleneck, have you considered a solid state drive (SSD)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to roll your own, it sounds like you may need a [ray caster/ray tracer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29).  A [ten year old paper](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/raytracing_series/State-of-the-Art%20in%20interactive%20ray%20tracing.pdf) describes the state of the art (back then): you have to convert the surface to a TIN and create a 3D data structure (the authors propose a BSP tree of voxels) to expedite finding the intersections.  Maybe you could get hold of a [ray tracing engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ray_tracing_software) and deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This will come in handy when/if I have to roll my own to meet my requirements.

Comment: @Chris In [a series of comments](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7644/how-to-calculate-the-visible-sky-percentage/7655#7655), @Dan S. gives useful advice and analysis concerning ray-casting.